# Парсинг вывода команды Powershell

Tags: powershell

Имеется команда:

> whoami /USER

Мне необходимо спарсить имя пользователя и SID, т.е должна быть строка содержащая это. Есть вариант выводить результат в формате CSV (whoami /USER /FO CSV), только вот Import-CSV принимает имя файла, а не строку. Какие возможные решения существуют для этой задачи?

Comment: Зачем парсить вывод, если Powershell и так выдаёт _объекты_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> только вот Import-CSV принимает имя файла, а не строку

`ConvertFrom-Csv` пока никто не отменял, но я бы делал это по другому:

```
$SecurityIdentifier = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User
$NTAccount = $SecurityIdentifier.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$NTAccount.Value
$SecurityIdentifier.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() | Select @{n='Пользователь';e={$_.Name}},@{n='SID';e={$_.user.value}}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].